# has set the IBOutlet by code but can not see outlets

Tags: ios, iphone

MyView.m code is

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyView : UIView
{

}

@property (strong, nonatomic)IBOutlet UILabel *aLabel;
```

but when I open the xib file MyView.xib relates to MyView.h/MyView.m(has set the file owner as Myview,
I can not see the IBOutlet aLabel

Is there a way can make UIView also can show IBOutlet aLabel, just like an UIViewController does?

Your comment welcome

[image]

Comment: Check your Outlets in your view not under the file's owner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your Outlets in your view not under the file's owner. See the screenshot.

[image]

[image]

Comment: ther is nothing neither

Comment: Set the class as `MyView` instead of `UIView` in the storyboard or Xib.

Comment: I made mistake file owner I set to another class, if I correct, outlet can be seen on file owner

Comment: Yes, you can also achieve using this way. But this is not the right way in case you are creating custom views using Xib, bcos sometime the file's owner may be different when you are going to use this view.

Answer (score 1):

First, your object is sub-class of UIView, which isn't can be natively relate to a xib. You should use UIViewController instead.

2nd. In case of you want to use an UIView in a xib, here is the way you can have it:

1. open your xib, click in the view that you want to turn it as your class.
2. open the right-side menu, and select the 3rd tab.
3. fill "class" field as your class name.
4. and now you can right click to the view and see your IBOutlet